# sns.pairplot shows density curve instead of histogram

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

My understanding is that the below code shall produce histograms in the diagonal boxes. Instead, I am getting density curves? Why is this? If I remove 'hue','palette' and 'diag_kws', it produces histograms as expected. Any inputs?

```
sns.pairplot(data=ins_pre,
        vars=["fatal_collisions", "premiums",'insurance_losses'],
        kind='scatter',
        hue='Region',
        palette='RdBu',
        diag_kws={'alpha':.5})

plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

[image]

Plot the same data but remove 'hue','palette' and 'diag_kws'

```
sns.pairplot(data=ins_pre,
        vars=["fatal_collisions", "premiums",'insurance_losses'],
        kind='scatter')

plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html):

> ```
> seaborn.pairplot(data, hue=None, hue_order=None, palette=None, vars=None, x_vars=None, 
> y_vars=None, kind='scatter', diag_kind='auto', markers=None, height=2.5, aspect=1,
> corner=False, dropna=True, plot_kws=None, diag_kws=None, grid_kws=None, size=None)
>
> [...]
>
> diag_kind{‘auto’, ‘hist’, ‘kde’, None}, optional
> Kind of plot for the diagonal subplots. The default depends on whether "hue" is used or not.
> ```

So, you should call the function like so:

```
sns.pairplot(data=ins_pre,
        vars=["fatal_collisions", "premiums",'insurance_losses'],
        kind='scatter',
        hue='Region',
        palette='RdBu',
        diag_kind='hist')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. As per documentation, what you said is correct. However, when I execute the code on a Jupyter notebook in the cloud, I get histograms even without specifying 'diag_kind' argument. It doesn't do so on my desktop Jupyter notebook. Don't know why..

Comment: says in the documentation: `Kind of plot for the diagonal subplots. The default depends on whether "hue" is used or not.` Could this have anything to do with it?

Comment: rechecked. In the cloud with 'hue' it is producing histograms, while on desktop, it is producing density plot when 'diag_kind' is not used.